# Выборка трех таблиц и сумма групп записей

Tags: sql, sqlite

Помогите пожалуйста составить SQL запрос.
Необходимо подсчитать количество всех действий пользователей каждой страны.
Вот мои таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE Cart (
            id   INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
            Time DATETIME,
            User INTEGER REFERENCES User (id),
            Goods_id INTEGER,
            Amount INTEGER,
            Cart_id INTEGER,
            Success_pay BOOLEAN);

        CREATE TABLE Purchase (
            id   INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
            Time DATETIME,
            User INTEGER REFERENCES User (id),
            Cart_id INTEGER REFERENCES Cart (id),
            Pay_user_id INTEGER);

        CREATE TABLE Action (
            id   INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
            Time DATETIME,
            User INTEGER REFERENCES User (id),
            Category INTEGER REFERENCES Category (id),
            Goods INTEGER REFERENCES Goods (id));

        CREATE TABLE Goods (
            id       INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
            Name     TEXT (50),
            Category INTEGER      REFERENCES Category (id));

        CREATE TABLE User (
            id      INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
            IP      TEXT (20) UNIQUE,
            Country TEXT (50));

        CREATE TABLE Category (
            id       INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
            Category TEXT (50) UNIQUE);
```

Мне удалось составить запрос для одной таблицы:

```
SELECT User.Country, COUNT() AS "Amount"
FROM User
       JOIN Purchase ON Purchase.User = User.id
WHERE User.Country != ''
GROUP BY User.Country
ORDER BY "Amount" DESC`
```

Но при попытке объеденить все три таблицы получаю недостоверные значения.

```
SELECT User.Country, COUNT() AS "Amount"
FROM User
       JOIN Action ON Action.User = User.id
       JOIN Cart ON Cart.User = User.id
       JOIN Purchase ON Purchase.User = User.id
WHERE User.Country != ''
GROUP BY User.Country
ORDER BY "Amount" DESC`
```

Comment: Что значит недостоверные сведения? Приведите в вопросе пример данных которые получаете, и что по вашему мнению с ними не так.

Comment: United States 16062  
China 4868  
United Kingdom 2195  
Germany 1568  
Malaysia 874  
Belgium 855  
Japan 793  
Taiwan 698

Comment: Если суммировать отдельно значения трех таблиц, то получается так: США: 9189
Китай: 2214
Британия: 731
Япония: 730
Германия: 685
Корея: 548, т.е. он где-то у меня считает лишние строки.

Answer (score 0):

думаю проблема в том что в Action и Cart есть несколько записей по одному юзеру потому записи дублируются, или их там нет поэтому записи пропадают. Составь запрос по другому

```
SELECT User.Country, COUNT() AS "Amount"
FROM User
       INNER JOIN Purchase ON Purchase.User = User.id
       LEFT  JOIN (select User Action group by User) A ON A.User = User.id
       LEFT  JOIN (select User Cart group by User) C ON C.User = User.id           
WHERE User.Country != ''
GROUP BY User.Country
ORDER BY "Amount" DESC`
```